# Can't pass String to Intent & start service

Tags: android, android-intent

Activity:

```
String id = "blabla";  
 Intent musicService = new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class);
                musicService.putExtra("MUSIC_ID", id);
                startService(musicService);
```

Service:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String s = extras.getString("musicID");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service start" + s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


     return START_STICKY;
    }
```

The toasts are never shown, and the intent/startservice lines in the activity are 100% hit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what device on are you testing? there used to be a bug on gingerbread

Comment: fixed it, s3 on cm10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you mis type your musicID

```
"MUSIC_ID"
```

you should make constant variables for these:

```
public static final String MUSIC_ID_KEY = "MUSIC_ID";
```

so you get less errors like this.

Comment: I hadn't. Thank you. Will select as best answer in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The tag in the `put` method must match the tag in the `get` method. Try changing the `getString` to the following:

```
    String s = extras.getString("MUSIC_ID");
```

Comment: Which one? Both? You have two.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it takes only the String you want to display in parameter :

```
 public void displayToast(final String str) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }             
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

They are two things. MUSIC_ID <-> musicID . Try to use 
static final String KEY_x = "MUSIC_ID";
And you will not forget it in your codes.